# Select into is inserting only 1 record

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a query to get all the lawyers and other relevant information stored as a json:

```
SELECT 
    key as table, trim(both '"' from json_array_elements(value)::text) as column
FROM json_each(( 
    SELECT ed.value::json FROM (SELECT * FROM config_setting WHERE name = 'lawyers') ed ))
WHERE
    key = 'user'
GROUP BY trim(both '"' from json_array_elements(value)::text), key
```

And this query returns me 2 records (That is what I'm expecting).

and once I try to assign it to a variable in my function, it only returns 1 record:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somefuncname() RETURNS tablearray LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
    DECLARE _rec tablearray;
    DECLARE total int;
    BEGIN
        SELECT t.column INTO _rec FROM  (
            SELECT 
                key as table, 
                trim(both '"' from json_array_elements(value)::text) as column
            FROM json_each(( 
                SELECT ed.value::json FROM (SELECT * FROM config_setting WHERE name = 'lawyers') ed ))
            WHERE
                key = 'user'
            GROUP BY trim(both '"' from json_array_elements(value)::text), key
        ) t;        
        RETURN _rec;
    END
$$;

SELECT * from somefuncname();
```

The `tablearray` definition is very simple, is just a table with one column (NO PK).

Why my function is just returning 1 row instead of 2? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select multiple records into variable. If you want the function to return multiple records, then use:

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT t.column FROM (........) t;
```